# How to use a method in a lib?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working to integrate UserVoice Single Single On with my rails app. They provide the following class for ruby:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ezcrypto'
require 'json'
require 'cgi'
require 'base64'

module Uservoice
  class Token
    attr_accessor :data

    USERVOICE_SUBDOMAIN = "FILL IN"
    USERVOICE_SSO_KEY = "FILL IN"

    def initialize(options = {})
      options.merge!({:expires => (Time.zone.now.utc + 5 * 60).to_s})

      key = EzCrypto::Key.with_password USERVOICE_SUBDOMAIN, USERVOICE_SSO_KEY
      encrypted = key.encrypt(options.to_json)
      @data = Base64.encode64(encrypted).gsub(/\n/,'') # Remove line returns where are annoyingly placed every 60 characters
    end

    def to_s
      @data
    end
  end
end
```

What I can't figure out is how to use this. I added this file to my lib directory and am using Rails Console to run. I tried:

```
1.9.3-p125 :013 > Uservoice::Token
 => Uservoice::Token
```

But can't get it to actually return for the options:

```
Uservoice::Token.new(:guid => 1, :display_name => "jeff goldmen", :email => "jeff@google.com")
```

Any ideas how to actually use this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/iltempo/uservoice/blob/master/lib/uservoice/token.rb), it doesn't appear that the initializer (what gets run when you call `new`) will take just a hash.  The method definition looks like this:

```
def initialize(key, api_key, data)
```

And it seems to treat the `data` variable as a hash.  You might just need to add the `key` and `api_key` values when you instantiate a Token.  So a call would look like this:

```
Uservoice::Token.new(KEY, API_KEY, {guid:1, display_name:'foo', email:'f@b.com'})
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't get how to call this function outside of the class. I need to pass it guid, display name and email? Ideas? Thanks

Comment: FYI, the link you provided is 3 years old. The class I pasted above is the latest that I'm trying to use. Thanks

Comment: Where's your library source?  The github I'm looking at is linked to by rubygems.

Comment: There appears to be an officially supported gem https://developer.uservoice.com/docs/api/ruby-sdk/ but its api is completely different.  I can't find the source you posted.